# Loading RAR which uses jffi causes JBoss/JVM to segfault

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

I have a rar which internally has within it the `jffi-1.2.9-native.jar` library - and loading this rar causes the jvm to segfault - with the following error:

```
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library
 <path
 to>/wildfly/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deploymentb41f06df572811e7/jffi-1.2.9-native.jar-d3417b30dd3cfd1/contents/jni/x86_64-Windows/jffi-1.2.dll
 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the
 stack guard now. It's highly recommended that you fix the library with
 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 #
 #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9f0990e938, pid=28629, tid=140320456898304
 #
 # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-25)
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 # Problematic frame:
 # C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x6938]  _dl_map_object_from_fd+0x898
```

What I don't understand is why this is trying to load this dll when the platform that I'm running on is:

```
Linux <machine> 3.0.101-0.15-default #1 SMP Wed Jan 22 15:49:03 UTC 2014 (5c01f4e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My question is - has anyone seen this kind of problem before - and what causes the windows dll to be loaded here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post an answer incase anyone hits something similar. I didn't get to the real root of the problem. My workaround was to re-organize the EAR, so now all the external dependencies are collected together into the EAR and all the other sub modules (such as EJB and WAR) specify a `<scope>provided</scope>` in the maven dependencies. Thus the WAR and the EJB contains no external dependencies. This means that the maven dependencies have to be specified in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

The only possiblity I could think of, why a `*.dll` instead of a `*.so` is tried to be loaded, is that the system property `os.name` is passed to the JVM and specifies a wrong operating system.

```
class OsName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    }
}
```

If you run the example as `java -Dos.name=FooBar` the output is `OS: FooBar`.

Comment: Actually - I just fixed it by re-organizing the contents of the EAR (which the RAR is deployed as part of) I moved all the libraries up to the EAR and this makes the issue "dissappear"...